# How to forbidden vim-go auto build when saving a *.go file

Tags: vim, go

[image]

I use vim-go, but I don't like it auto build executable file when save a go source file. How to forbidden it?

Comment: By default, `vim-go` does not auto-build. You need to explicitly call `:GoBuild` (or a keybinding that maps to that) as per https://github.com/fatih/vim-go#mappings

If your installation is automatically building executables, can you explain how you are saving files and/or whether you are running the latest version of vim-go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not vim-go but syntastic do this, just config

let g:syntastic_go_checkers = []